# in debug mode flutter website generate qr code and also install locally. but a after release no error no working

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-hosting

When i test app in debug flutter web successfully create and save qr code but when I release this website and host it on firebase this not working not showing a single message or warning what is heppening.

```
class _QRBoxWidgetState extends State<QRBoxWidget> {
  WidgetsToImageController controller = WidgetsToImageController();
  final storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
  final GlobalKey globalKey = GlobalKey();
  final home = Get.put(HomeController());

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget qr = RepaintBoundary(
      key: globalKey,
      child: WidgetsToImage(
        controller: controller,
        child: Container(
          height: height(context) * 0.1,
          width: height(context) * 0.1,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: CustomPaint(
            // painter: Painter(),
            painter: QrPainter(
                data: "Tanveer Ahmad",
                options: const QrOptions(
                    shapes: QrShapes(
                        darkPixel: QrPixelShapeRoundCorners(cornerFraction: .5),
                        frame:  QrFrameShapeRoundCorners(cornerFraction: .25),
                        ball: QrBallShapeRoundCorners(cornerFraction: .25)
                    ),
                    colors: QrColors(
                        dark: QrColorLinearGradient(
                            colors: [
                              Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 0, 0),
                              Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 255)
                            ],
                            orientation: GradientOrientation.leftDiagonal
                        )
                    )
                )),
            size: const Size(350, 350),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
    return Bounceable(
      onTap: widget.onTap,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          qr,
          Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              IconButtonWidget(onTap: () => downloadQrCode(qr), iconPath: AppIcons.downloadIcon),
              IconButtonWidget(onTap: () => download2(), iconPath: AppIcons.downloadIcon),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void download2() async {
    ByteData byteData = await WidgetToImage.repaintBoundaryToImage(globalKey);
    saveImage(byteData.buffer.asUint8List(),"Tanveer");
  }
  void saveImage(Uint8List imageData, String filename) {
    final blob = html.Blob([imageData], 'image/png');
    final url = html.Url.createObjectUrlFromBlob(blob);
    final anchor =html.AnchorElement(href: url)
      ..download = filename
      ..click();
    html.Url.revokeObjectUrl(url);
  }
  void downloadQrCode(Widget qr) async {
    Uint8List? uint8list = await controller.capture();
    if(uint8list != null){
      try{
        TaskSnapshot task =  await storage.ref("qr_code/${widget.qrCode.qrCodeId}.png").putData(uint8list);
        final url = await task.ref.getDownloadURL();
        final anchor = html.AnchorElement(href: url);
        anchor.download = 'file_name.extension';
        anchor.click();
      }catch(e){
        Get.dialog(Dialog(
          child: Text("Image Caperture IIsuue $e",textScaleFactor: 5,),
        ));
      }
    } else {
      Get.dialog(Dialog(
        child: Text("Image Caperture IIsuue",textScaleFactor: 5,),
      ));
    }
  }
}
```

this code is not showing any issue in debug mode but after release not saving image even to firebase storage but also not showing any error message or warning.